# Assigning values to elements of a list based on random choice

Tags: python, list, random

I am currently attempting to program Conway's game of life, and am currently at the stage where I am simply attempting to initialize a randomized board.

I began by creating a list of 1000 elements, each one a list containing 1000 0s (essentially a 1000x1000 empty board).

The code I am using to update the 0s to 1s is the following:

```
def initialize(board):
    numlist=[1,2,3]
    for i,v in enumerate(board):
        for j,w in enumerate(v):
            if random.choice(numlist)==1:
                board[i][j]=1
    return board
```

However, when I run this function on the empty board noted above, every single value in the list is set to 1. I have also attempting to code this as the following:

```
def initialize(board):
    for i,v in enumerate(board):
        for j,w in enumerate(v):
            x=stats.uniform.rvs()
            if x<=.33:
                board[i][j]=1
    return board
```

I am having some trouble understanding why the output is a list of all 1s, instead of the desired output of the board where ~1/3 of the tiles are 1s. I have reviewed the code numerous times, and I am not seeing why this result keeps occurring.

How can I accomplish the goal I have put forth, namely assigning ~1/3 of the 1000x1000 tiles to be 1s? Any advice or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You didn't show us the essential thing: how you create the empty board.

Comment: Anyway, this is almost certainly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

I have determined that the answer was to turn the list of lists into a numpy array, that solved the problem right away!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably with the original `board` that you passed in.  If you started with something like:

```
board = [[0] * 1000] * 1000
```

then you have 1000 references to the same list, not 1000 different lists.  Any modification you make is to the same shared list.

I'd initialize the board with something like:

```
board = [[random.choice([0, 0, 1]) for _ in range(1000)] for _ in range(1000)]
```

With a nested comprehension, the inner loop is executed multiple times inside the outer loop, giving you multiple unique lists; this is different from list multiplication, where the contents of the list are simply duplicated.